# Windows Terminal Azure Cloud shell display issue

Tags: windows

In windows terminal (latest version) I am trying to open an Azure Cloud Shell.  Functionality is working, however I am unable to read the display as when I set focus to the window, it becomes obscured (foreground shading is applied).  When I select a different window, the terminal returns to normal.

Does anyone know how to change the theme to something useful or to turn off this foreground shading?

Regards

Comment: i'd post a bug report here: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

Answer (score 0):

In writing out the bug as mentioned above I found I needed to delete my old settings file. Once I did this, and restarted terminal it started working.

I note when the azure shell is started, it briefly becomes transparent before updating itself.